# create singel dataframe from multiple csv sources and create singel excel file from dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I need help with my Python code.
The goal is:

1. read in between 100 and 200 CSV files that are in a folder
2. copy a variable in each CSV file from position (2,2)
3. create the sum of all values of column 17 in every CSV
4. to transfer the values in the form of a dataframe
5. create a new Excel file
6. transfer the dataframe in the Excel file
   My attempt was the following code

```
# import necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
  
  
# use glob to get all the csv files 
# in the folder
path = os.getcwd()
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
  
  
# loop over the list of csv files
for f in csv_files:
      
    # read the csv file
    df = pd.read_csv(f,sep=';', skiprows=2,usecols=[2,16],header=None)
    #ID
    ID = (df.loc[2][2])
    #summ of col.16
    dat_Verbr = df[16].sum()
 
# data in single dataframe
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'SIM-Karte': ID, 'Datenverbrauch': dat_Verbr}, index=[0,1,2,3,4,5])


# Specify the name of the excel file
file_name = 'Auswertung.xlsx'
  
# saving the excelsheet
concatenated.to_excel(file_name)
print(' record successfully exported into Excel File')
```

unfortunately, it doesn't work.

1. Problem is that only the first id and first sum are imported in the excel file.
2. How can I work with the index by creating a single dataframe. I don’t know the exact number of csv files, only somewhat between 100 and 200.
   I'm a beginner with python.
   Can someone help me please?

Comment: sorry, mistake in last line df4.to_excel(file_name)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the updated code. One assumption I made is that there is data in all rows 1 thru 16. If your file has just `;;;;...` in the first row, read_csv sometimes makes a mistake. Also, as you are using `skiprow = 1`, it will not add the value in row 1, column 17 if present. You can need to change the code if that needs to be added. Rest, I have corrected/changed so the code works. Note that in `to_excel` I have used `index=False` as I didnt think you need the index to be added. Remove if you want to see the index as well.

```
# use glob to get all the csv files 
# in the folder
import os, glob
path = os.getcwd()
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
  
# data in single dataframe
df4 = pd.DataFrame(columns =['SIM-Karte', 'Datenverbrauch'])
  
# loop over the list of csv files
for f in csv_files:
      
    # read the csv file
    df = pd.read_csv(f,sep=';', skiprows = 1, usecols=[1,16],header=None)
    #ID
    ID = (df.iloc[0][1])
    #summ of col.16
    dat_Verbr = df[16].sum()
    df4.loc[len(df4.index)] = [ID, dat_Verbr]

# Specify the name of the excel file
file_name = 'Auswertung.xlsx'
  
# saving the excelsheet
df4.to_excel(file_name, index=False)
print(' record successfully exported into Excel File')
```

**Output excel** - I had 3 files in the folder

[image]